# Fresh install tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I installed tensorflow using pip earlier (CPU only version). It was showing me some warnings whenever I used to work with it. Now I tried to install the GPU version. Now when I `import tensorflow`, it gives a bunch of errors.

So I wanted to know if there was a way to completely delete tensorflow from Ubuntu and then reinstall it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pip packages can be uninstalled `pip uninstall tensorflow`. Make sure you are uninstalling it from the environment of concern (if applicable).The pip output will inform you of it's successful removal. This should be enough to remove tensorflow from your system. You can then `pip install tensorflow --ignore-installed` to reinstall. The `--ignore-install` flag should overwrite tensorflow if you're concerned it was not successfully removed.

Please note that if you tried to install tensorflow GPU version that you will need to uninstall using `tensorflow-gpu` isntead of `tensorflow`. Same for re-installing.

Regarding your other issues, I suggest you open a fresh question for your errors. There's a good chance you weren't receiving errors but just the standard info messages from Tensorflow-GPU.

Comment: If I uninstall both using tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu. Then to reinstall, would pip install work or should I install from source. Because earlier when I installed tensorflow using pip, when I used to run simple scripts,  it used to give me warnings like TensorFlow was not compiled using SSE instructions. Also would I need to install only gpu version then?

Comment: pip should work fine. I reinstall and install all the time. Those warnings are perfectly normal. You can install from pip and have those warnings. They're not really warnings anyway they're more information messages letting you know you could get performance benefits. If you want to open a fresh question and post the link here I can help you further.